Astro-Mechanics: Plausibility check for binary system merge
I have a binary system composed primary about a brown dwarf and a k6.6V star that's the fusion of the system 1 and 2 7.41 billion years ago, I'll tell you the story and I'll ask the question after the story. Below the question there are diagrams that I made in blender3d to help you find the answer and that you can see it visually.
7410 million years ago a young planetary system with an star in it's center is being formed, in it's path another planetary system approaches and inevitably gets closer and closer. This planetary system is much more small and more ancient (It was formed 8070 million years ago), a carbon planet (1.5-2.3 Earth masses) and a brown dwarf (63.2 Jupiter masses) in it's center with a carbonaceous asteroid belt. The carbon planet disengages from the brown dwarf and orbits the star between 0.8 AU and 5 AU. After that the brown dwarf kidnaps a protoplanet while stabilizing at 0.45 AU.
My question is: Could this fusion be possible and how would it affect my exoplanets, specially the kidnapped planet?
(What would contradict this merge by known physics?)
(How can I compute or estimate possible/plausible orbital distances for the bodies in a planetary system?)



Notes: The oort cloud is a provisional name for the vast cloud of icy planetesimals.
Thanks for taking your time.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
